# How can I hide internal APIs on a SpringBoot service standing behind a TCP load balancer

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot-actuator

I’m wondering what the best practice is for only exposing certain APIs on a SpringBoot service. For context I have a service that will be sitting behind a TCP load balancer which has some apis that will be called from a web page. However, I’d like to limit which APIs are exposed, like a metrics scraping endpoint for Prometheus and some other actuator type endpoints.

I was thinking of standing up an NGINX instance on each service host and proxying requests to the instance on the same host. In that way, I think I could limit which APIs are available publicly. But I’d like to know what other options are recommended or available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Springboot has a configuration that allows you to expose the actuator endpoints on a different port. Using Spring boot version `2.7.X` I was able to do the following:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,prometheus
management.server.port=9090
```

Changing this port does not affect the normal server port that http requests are served from.